# Mysql: Select rows in which all fields are equal

Tags: mysql, database, sorting, duplicates, unique

How to remove (or select) all unique rows from a mysql db?

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| FirstName | LastName | BirthDate |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| Tia | Carrera | 1975-09-18 |
| Tia | Carrera | 1975-09-18 |
| Nikki | Taylor | 1972-03-04 |
| Yamila | Taylor | 1972-03-04 |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

The removed or selected rows must be an **exact** duplicate. Example output

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| FirstName | LastName | BirthDate |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| Tia | Carrera | 1975-09-18 |
| Nikki | Taylor | 1972-03-04 |
| Yamila | Taylor | 1972-03-04 |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a `SELECT DISTINCT` query instead of a `SELECT` query.

Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    BirthDate

FROM YourTable;
```

This will collapse all identical rows into one result.

Comment: thanks, got it working with `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM YourTable;`